# Handling different payment amount formats

Tags: python, format

I'm struggling since I cannot find proper Python function or library that would handle different amount formats from reports that I receive in `.xslx` format.

Sometimes, report includes payment amounts in format such as `1.000.000,00 €`, other-times `1,000,000.00€`, as a string. Be aware that sometime amount does not exceed `1000€` therefore amount could be `999,00€` or `999.0€`

How should I handle such amount formats into common `float` format `1,000,000.00€` ? Is there any simple function to handle all this formats?

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple conditions to meet here. But with some logic, you can use `re.sub` to remove the unneeded chars and cast to `float`:

```
import re

def clean(x):

    dc = x.count('.')
    cc = x.count(',')

    sep = max((dc, '.'), (cc, ','), key=lambda x: x[0])[1]

    if dc != 0:
        # There are decimals
        if dc > 1:
            x = re.sub(f'[.€\s]', '', x)
        else:
            x = re.sub(f'[,€\s]', '', x)
    else:
        # Insert deciaml
        x = x.replace(',', '.')
        x = re.sub(f'[€\s]', '', x)

    if sep == '.':
        x = x.replace(',', '.')

    return float(x)
```

```
>>> for i in ['1.000.000,00 €', '1,000,000.00€', '999,00€', '999.0€']:
...     print(clean(i))
... 
1000000.0
1000000.0
999.0
999.0
```

---

`dc` is the count of *dots* or `'.'`

`cc` is the count of *commas* or `','`

`sep` is the most common separator

Pseudocode:

```js
IF there are any '.' in x
    IF there is > 1 '.' in x
        // You are using the '.' separator
        remove '.' separator, symbol and whitespace from x
    ELSE
        // You are using the ',' separator
        remove ',' separator, symbol and whitespace from x
ELSE
    // You need to manually add the '.' point
    replace ',' with '.' in x
    remove symbol and whitespace from x

IF x uses the '.' separator
     replace ',' with '.' in x
```

> [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vI6u9M/1)
>
> Good [website](https://regexone.com/) to learn regex

Comment: That's not going to work for x = '1.000.000,00€'

Comment: @LancelotduLac, noted - fixing now

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan what about case if amount is 999,00€, replace return 99900 (100x higher amount).

Comment: @MachuPichu92, yeah i didn't realise. I have edited my answer to account for those scenarios